# Spring3 integration with Struts2

Tags: java, spring, struts2

Trying to integrate Spring3.x with struts2-2.2.1 and have placed all the required Spring 3.x files in the classpath

- org.springframework.aop-3.0.2.RELEASE
- org.springframework.asm-3.0.2.RELEASE
- org.springframework.context-3.0.2.RELEASE
- org.springframework.core-3.0.2.RELEASE
- org.springframework.web-3.0.2.RELEASE

as well as

- struts2-spring-plugin-2.2.1

in my web.xml the entries are as follow

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

i have already defined the required object factory in my struts.properties file as

```
struts.objectFactory = org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory
```

but nothing seems working and my tomcat server giving me the following error in consloe

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/FatalBeanException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2733)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
2 Jan, 2011 12:14:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
2 Jan, 2011 12:14:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

can any one point me what exactly is wrong
thanks in advance

after adding the required jar its stopped giving the error but now giving another issue

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:481)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
2011-01-02 00:41:09,970 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor
```

i have placed applicationContext.xml file in the class path with no bean deficnition yet
something like

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


</beans>
```

do i need to do something diffrent ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need

- `org.springframework.beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar`
- `org.springframework.expression-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar`

Comment: I really hate the new Spring packaging.  I don't like having to fetch all the dependencies.  I think they've taken a step back with their OSGi direction.

Comment: i am first time trying to use Spring and its making me to dance on its tune..any idea what exactly i need to do?

Comment: @umesh: See edited answer. Basically, when you get these, you need to look through the various JARs in the Spring distro to find the one that has the class you need. It's not a great way of doing it, as @duffymo says, but that's what you need to do.

Comment: Finally it seems working for my thanks Skaffman for the quick help

Comment: you really should move to using Maven for managing dependencies.  It just takes care of all that crap...